# Keyvalue-command: Add option for boolean key

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, key-value, expkv

I have a boolean  key `map` that produces TikZ-stuff (right column) like

[image]

I would like to have an additional *key*-option like `map=red` 
with which I can *access the TikZ options*, in the sense of `\node[text=<color>]`. 
In the example, the 1st output should then appear red. 
(The second example does not change here, since no map option was used.)

Whats the best way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\newcommand\TheSymbol{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[]  {S0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheMap{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[] {S0(\n)};
\end{tikzpicture}}}


\ekvdefinekeys{cmd}{
  ,boolTF map = \mymapTF
}
\newcommand\cmd[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \ekvset{cmd}{#1}%
    \mymapTF{\TheMap}{\TheSymbol}%
    \endgroup
}


% For the presentation: 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=white, colframe=white, fontupper=\ttfamily,
enhanced, borderline south={1pt}{-2pt}{black}, listing side text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
\cmd[map]         
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
\cmd[]        
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will use pgfkeys................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 0.4 (released on 2020-07-04) of `expkv-def` one can define an action for an unknown choice (and since a `boolTF` key is internally the same as a `choice` key with the choices `true` and `false` and appropriate actions we can use the `unknown-choice` prefix for `map`). This can be used to define an action which we can use to set the `text` key of `pgf` (I'm doing this by defining a macro `\mymap@node` which is used instead of `\node`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{expkv-def}[2020-07-04]

\newcommand\TheSymbol{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[]  {S0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\TheMap{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\mymap@node {S0(\n)};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\ekvdefinekeys{cmd}{
   boolTF map = \mymapTF
  ,unknown-choice map=\let\mymapTF\@firstoftwo\def\mymap@node{\node[{text=#1}]}
}
\newcommand*\mymap@node{\node}
\makeatother
\newcommand\cmd[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \ekvset{cmd}{#1}%
    \mymapTF{\TheMap}{\TheSymbol}%
    \endgroup
}


% For the presentation: 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=white, colframe=white, fontupper=\ttfamily,
enhanced, borderline south={1pt}{-2pt}{black}, listing side text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
\cmd[map]\par
\cmd[map=true]\par
\cmd[map=green]\par
\cmd[map=red]\par
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
\cmd[]\par
\cmd[map=false]\par
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]